# How to order SQL rows by value?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

How to **select** user_ids **by B** meta_key and **order by ratings** meta_value?

```
    user_id    |    meta_key    |    meta_value
-----------------------------------------------------
       1                A                1
       1                B                1
       1                C                1
       1              rating             9
       8                A                1
       8                C                1
       8              rating           99999
       7                A                1
       7                B                1
       7                C                1
       7              rating            999
```

I need to get an IDs of users who have **B** meta_key and, then, to order IDs by user **rating** values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```sql
SELECT T1.user_id
    FROM yourtable T1 
    JOIN yourtable T2
        ON T1.user_id = T2.user_id
        AND T2.meta_key = 'rating'
    WHERE T1.meta_key = 'B'
    ORDER BY CAST(T2.meta_value AS SIGNED)
```

Comment: You're right. Didn't see the `wordpress` tag and didn't think enough.

Comment: Mark, that works like a charm! I could not get to do it by myself by using the JOIN. Thank you so much!

Comment: However, meta_value is a string, therefore, an ordering isn't working correctly. Is there way to convert meta_value to integer?

Comment: @MarkByers: Fixed. I'm really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

To do this, you need a self join:

```
select t.*
from t left outer join
     (select t.user_id, max(meta_value) as rating
      from t
      where t.meta_key = 'rating'
      group by t.user_id
     ) r
     on t.user_id = r.user_id
where meta_key = 'B'
order by r.rating
```